# UITableView RowSelected not being called?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and a subclassed `UITableViewSource` class:

```
table = new UITableView(window.Bounds);
table.Source = new CellSource();

public class CellSource : UITableViewSource
{
    // etc etc
```

I'm trying to get the selected row, so implemented the `RowSelected` method in my source class:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableview, NSIndexPath indexpath) {
    Console.WriteLine("User tapped");
}
```

However, tapping on the cells gives no response at all, not even when simply trying to write to the console.

I can post the complete classes if that will help?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

So, after I create my `UITableView`:

```
table = new UITableView(window.Bounds);
table.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
table.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
table.Source = new CellSource();
```

I use my source class to parse an XML file, and populate a list:

```
List<Treasure> treasures = new List<Treasure>();

protected class Treasure {
    public string cellTitle { get; set; }
    public string cellTag { get; set; }
    public string cellImage { get; set; }
    public string audioFile { get; set; }
    public string mainTitle { get; set; }
    public string mainTag { get; set; }
    public string mainBody { get; set; }
    public string mainImage { get; set; }
    public string mainCaption { get; set; }
}

public CellSource (/*string[] items*/)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CellSource called");
    string fileName = "treasuresiPhone.xml";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    treasures = doc.Descendants("treasures").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("treasure").Select(p=> new Treasure() {
        cellTitle = p.Element("celltitle").Value,
        cellTag = p.Element("celltagline").Value,
        cellImage = p.Element("cellimage").Value
    }).ToList();

    numCells = treasures.Count();       
}
```

I then create a `CGBitmapContext` in another class, return the image, and set this as the cells image:

```
public UIImage DrawCell (string cellImage) {
    string cellI = cellImage;
    //create a new graphics context
    int width = 320;
    int height = 110;
    CGBitmapContext ctx = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, width, height, 8, 4*width, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst);

    //load an image
    var imagePath = (@cellI);
    var image = UIImage.FromFile(imagePath).CGImage;
    ctx.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height), image);

    UIImage returnedImage = new UIImage();
    returnedImage = FromImage(ctx.ToImage());

    return returnedImage;
}
```

I add some other test stuff like a label, and override the `RowSelected` method:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) {
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
    cell.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
    UILabel secondViewLabel = new UILabel();

    //if there are no cells create a new one
    if (cell == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("cell == null");
    } else {

        //create a new cellobject - this grabs the image and returns a CGBitmapContext
        CellObject _cellObject = new CellObject();
        cell.ImageView.Image = _cellObject.DrawCell(treasures[indexPath.Row].cellImage);

        //add text
        secondViewLabel.Tag = 1;
        secondViewLabel.Text = treasures[indexPath.Row].cellTitle;
        secondViewLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        secondViewLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        secondViewLabel.Lines = 0;
        secondViewLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        secondViewLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 16);
        secondViewLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(205, 54, 51);

        //get the width of the text
        SizeF labelSize = secondViewLabel.StringSize(secondViewLabel.Text, secondViewLabel.Font);

        secondViewLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 110 - (labelSize.Height + 10), labelSize.Width + 20, labelSize.Height + 10);

        //add a second view
        UIView secondView = new UIView();
        secondView.AddSubview(secondViewLabel);
        cell.ContentView.AddSubview(secondView);
    }
    return cell;
}

public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableview, NSIndexPath indexpath) {
    Console.WriteLine("User tapped");
}
```

Comment: are you also assigning a Delegate or DataSource to your view?

Comment: I'm guessing not, I just have the CellSource class which fills the table with data from XML.  I can't find anything too specific about assigning a DataSource, I've Googled but all the examples look very similar to what I'm doing already.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: are you doing anything else when you create the Table and assign properties, or is what you posted all of it?

Comment: I'll add additional detail up top.

Comment: cell.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Monotouch `UITableViewSource` is the combined `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` for a `UITableView`. So, when you extend such class you can take advantage of methods within both data source and delegate.

Said this, I would modify a little bit your code (see comments).

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

    // if there are no cells create a new one
    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);      

        // why do you set the interaction to false? Setting it to false disable interaction for your cell
        cell.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

        // create label and view here. You customize the cell with additional elements once

    }

    // update image and label here (you need to grab a reference for your label for example through the tag)

    return cell;
}
```

Take also a look to [Working with Tables and Cells](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables) in Xamarin documentation.

Hope it helps.